# ews php - Push notifications vs Streaming notifications

Tags: php, exchangewebservices, php-ews

I'm trying to sync all calendars in my exchange server with my app, and for that, I am using PHP-EWS: jamesiarmes/php-ews!

After some research, I found 2 options to consider:

1. Push notifications - I've worked with something similar before, in this case, I should know how it works!
2. Streaming notifications - I've never worked with this before and I don't understand it, do I need to check from x to x time if there are any notifications for the created channel?

Can you help me choose between the two of them since I don't understand the streaming notification to 100%?

Comment: There are three kinds of synchronization with EWS. Have a look on [Getting notifications - what are my options?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/notification-subscriptions-mailbox-events-and-ews-in-exchange#getting-notifications---what-are-my-options) This should give you an overview on how the different methods work. Maybe then you can choos a method.

Comment: @LuCio, I've seen that page before, I mentioned 2 options to consider because I think that the third option "Pull notifications" isn't appropriate for my user case! I need to know if "Streaming notifications" keeps asking what is new to the server! i don't understand that part, thanks for your help.

Comment: If your version of Exchange supports it, have you considered using the REST API or Microsoft Graph instead?  They have superseded EWS.  I think you'll have an easier time with notifications on those.

Comment: Yes, i considered the Rest API  or Microsoft Graph , but after speaking with someone from Microsoft they say the my case don't support it! Thank you lot again

Answer (score 1):

With **streaming notifications**, your client opens a long running HTTP request to the server and the server sends events in the HTTP response over a long period.  This can be done without additional software in the client.

With **push notifications**, you give the server a URL to send notifications to as HTTP requests.  This requires that the client have an HTTP server running and an application to process events.

I *believe* EWS only supports streaming notifications.  I'm not sure what that PHP library supports.

Comment: I understand it now! If what i read is correct, the PHP library support it
I will try it out!
Thanks you a lot for the help!